# Apply Model Scores to Spark DataFrame - Python

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I'm trying to apply a score to a Spark DataFrame using PySpark.  Let's assuming that I built a simple regression model outside of Spark and want to map the coefficient values created in the model to the individual columns in the DataFrame to create a new column that is the sum of each of the different source columns multiplied by the individual coefficients.  I understand that there are many utilities in Spark mllib for modeling, but I want to understand how this 'brute force' method could be accomplished.  I also know that DataFrames/RDDs are immutable, so a new DataFrame would have to be created.

Here's some pseudo-code for reference:

```
#load example data
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
df.show(5)
dfmappd.select("age", "parch", "pclass").show(5)
+----+-----+------+
| age|parch|pclass|
+----+-----+------+
|22.0|    0|     3|
|38.0|    0|     1|
|26.0|    0|     3|
|35.0|    0|     1|
|35.0|    0|     3|
+----+-----+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The model created outside of Spark is a logistic regression model based on a binary response.  So essentially I want to map the logit function to these three columns to produce a fourth scored column.  Here are the coefficients from the model:

intercept: 3.435222

age: -0.039841

parch: 0.176439

pclass: -1.239452

Here is a description of the logit function for reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

For comparison, here is how I would do the same thing in R using tidyr and dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Example data
Age <- c(22, 38, 26, 35, 35)
Parch <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
Pclass <- c(3, 1, 3, 1, 3)

#Wrapped in a dataframe
mydf <- data.frame(Age, Parch, Pclass)

#Using dplyr to create a new dataframe with mutated column
scoredf = mydf %>% 
  mutate(score = round(1/(1 + exp(-(3.435 + -0.040 * Age + 0.176 * Parch + -1.239 * Pclass))),2))
scoredf
```

Comment: What you are asking isn't clear ! You want to multiply your coefficient by the each observation feature ?

Comment: @eliasah, thank you for the feedback, I've updated the question with an example of how this would be accomplished in R for reference, hopefully this provides more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to compute the class conditional probability of each sample given the coefficients you computed offline and do it "manually".

Does something like this work:

```
def myLogisticFunc(age, parch, pclass):
  intercept = 3.435222
  betaAge = -0.039841
  betaParch = 0.176439
  betaPclass = -1.239452
  z = intercept + betaAge * age + betaParch * parch + betaPclass * pclass
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-z))

myLogisticFuncUDF = udf(myLogisticFunc)
df.withColumn("score", myLogisticFuncUDF(col("age"), col("parch"), col("pclass"))).show()
```

Comment: that's it! Thank you for your help.